# update image in laravel 8 - API

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried update my image, but it isn´t update.

1. I have the method upload , it works in a store method

```
    private function upload($image)
    {
        $path_info = pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName());`
        $post_path = 'images/post';
    
        $rename = uniqid() . '.' . $path_info['extension'];
        $image->move(public_path() . "/$post_path", $rename);
        return "$post_path/$rename";      
    }
```

1. I tried update the new image, but the message update successfully apears but not update

```
  public function update(Request $request, Car $car)
  {
      if (!empty($request->file('image_url'))) {
          $url_image = $this->upload($request->file('image_url'));
          $car->image_url = $url_image;
      }

      $res = $car->save();

      if ($res) {
          return response()->json(['message' => 'Car update succesfully']);
      }

      return response()->json(['message' => 'Error to update car'], 500);
  }
```

2. La actualización es correcta pero en la BDD no actualiza
   [Imagen de actualización con POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXUWI.png)

Comment: "La actualización es correcta pero en la BDD no actualiza Imagen de actualización con POSTMAN" maybe better in english ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method in postman to `POST` and add this query string parameter to the URL: its name is `_method` and the value is `PUT`.
Your API consumers will call the endpoint in this way but you will keep the route definition with the `PUT` verb. Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: No lo quiero editar desde un formulario, lo quiero editar consumiendo la API desde postman.

Answer (score 0):

The request `PUT` doesnt have a body like the method `POST` as of the RFCs (Something with the Content-Length, dont remember correctly).

Even if your API can handle PUT methods with body, your postman will try to send the file in the query field (URL) and that will mostly break the file. You can check the URL called by postman in the request Headers.

Laravel has a workaround for this, you send the parameter `_method=PUT` in a `POST` request and the router will handle it as a PUT request (if you declared it so).

Comment: No lo quiero editar desde un formulario, lo quiero editar consumiendo la API desde postman.

Comment: @CarlosTontaquimba in your Postman, change the request type to POST instead of PUT and add another field `_method` with value `put` and stop posting/commenting in espagnol, SO is strictly in english